# Confusion re: Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading Folland and am stumbling at 1.5 Borel Measures on the Real Line.

He says "We begin with a more general construction that yields a large family of measures on R whose domain is the Borel sigma-algebra Br; such measures are called Borel measures on R."

So a Borel measure is a function from the Borel sets of the sigma algebra Br --> [0, infinity].  But isn't the Borel sigma algebra Br a bit vague?  That is, the smallest sigma algebra that generates R doesn't seem well-defined to me...

Could someone clarify this a bit for me?

Thanks for the help,
Ben

Comment: It's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open subsets (of $\mathbb{R}$). It's perfectly well-defined, it's just not terribly easy to describe the Borel sets.

Answer (score 0):

The "smallest sigma algebra" is well-defined in the following precise sense:

Let $X$ be a set. If $\mathcal{F}$ is any collection of subsets of $X$, consider the family $\Omega$ of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal{F}$. Then the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras in $\Omega$ is itself a $\sigma$-algebra, which is commonly called the "smallest" $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{F}$. If you substitute $X=\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{F}$ for the collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then you get the Borel sets.

If you prefer a more constructive approach, Borel sets can also be generated from successively taking countable intersections, countable unions, and relative complements on the collection of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. The details are, for example, on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set

Comment: Ah ok, I think this makes sense.  Tho it's far from obvious to me why we should care much about Borel sets...maybe that's part of my confusion?  Also, I know what an open set in a topological space is but an open subset of R in what sense?  Sorry for the potentially silly q and thanks again!

Comment: Well, if you want a measure on all the open intervals, which agrees with the intuitive meaning of "length," and at the same time want measurability to be preserved under as many operations on the sets as possible, say countable unions and intersections, then it's natural to think of the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets.