# Seemingly Simple re: Generation of Sigma Algebras

Tags: measure-theory

On p. 22 of Folland, he gives this lemma:

1.1 Lemma. If $E \subset M(F)$, then $M(E) \subset M(F)$, where for $E \subset P(X)$, $M(E)$ is the unique smallest sigma algebra containing $E$.

Proof:

$M(F)$ is a sigma algebra containing $E$.  It therefore contains $M(E)$.

I'm stumbling on the second part of the proof.  Why does $E \subset M(F)$ imply $M(E) \subset M(F)$?  I don't really see why the smallest sigma algebra containing E must also contain the smallest sigma algebra containing E...

Thanks for the help guys,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off my answer to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623393/confusion-re-borel-measure/623403#623403).

Because the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $E$ (denoted $M(E)$) is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $E$, it is therefore contained in any $\sigma$-algebra containing $E$. Since $M(F)$ contains $E$, it must contain $M(E)$.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!